# Yeoman composeWith: change directory?

Tags: bower, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have a yeoman generator (GenA) that is using a sub-generator (GenB). GenA will create a `public/` folder in my application structure, and I want GenB to run from that folder and place all of its files within `/public` (mostly because I want to be able to install dependencies through Bower in GenB).

Relevant part of GenA:

```
prompting: function() {
  this.prompt(prompts, function(ans) {
    this.composeWith('GenB', {
      options: {
        application_name: this.application_name
      }
    },
    {
      local: require.resolve('path/to/GenB')
    });
    done();
  }.bind(this))
};
```

Relevant part of GenB:

```
this.bowConfig = {
  "directory": "public/bower_components"
};
this.fs.writeJSON('.bowerrc', this.bowConfig);

this.bow = {
  "name": this.name,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "foo",
  "dependencies": { ... },
  "devDependencies": { ... }
};
this.fs.writeJSON('bower.json', this.bow);

// and a little later...
install: function() {
  this.bowerInstall() // this looks for bower.json in the current directory
  // ...
}
```

If I change my settings to that I write to `public/bower.json` instead, then when yeoman calls `this.bowerInstall` it doesn't see my `bower.json` file and therefore doesn't install my dependencies.

If I try to change the root path for all of GenB, like so:

```
constructor: function () {
  generators.Base.apply(this, arguments);
  this.destinationRoot('public/')
}
```

then all generated files, including those from parent GenA, are generated based on the altered destinationRoot.

Is there another option to specify where to place files generated via a subgenerated & composeWith()? Should generating in a different directory than the parent generator be handled in a different way?

Any help is appreciated.

---

Comment: You should open an issue at https://github.com/yeoman/generator - changing destinationRoot actually does change it for everybody because of the way it works. We might be able to fix that somehow...

Comment: Related issue [here](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/issues/845).

Answer (score 1):

You can [spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) a command with specifying a cwd. You can spawn the bower process manually, specify a cwd and it'll work.

I'm not 100% sure it'll work, but maybe this will also work:

```
this.bowerInstall(null, {cwd: 'public/'});
```